# expect showing the same result for failure and success

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I wrote the following test -

```
it('should call api for valid input', (done) => {
      let response = myprocessor.processEvent(myEvent);
      done();
      expect(httpMock.http.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
```

httpMock is a mock object for a http call. While debugging, "httpMock.http.calledOnce" clearly evaluates to false, but still the test passes, whatever the value of the object being tested. Why is this happening?

Comment: The test will complete when you call `done()` and stop executing the assertion after it.

Comment: ok, I am new to NodeJS programming. Thank you for the clarification